# Bluetooth device is not listed

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

Device I have connected is my arduino board with bluetooth HC-05 which is Bluetooth 2.0 module. It shows in my Windows 10 bluetooth manager, that the device is ready to be paired (I can even pair it with no problem), however my UWP app seems not to find it:

[image: Device is ready to be paired, but no results in debug]

The variable "devices" is just null. Any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't understand whats off-topic here. It is question about UWP development and the code needed is in the screenshot. It doesn't metter if the device is arduino module or whatever bluetooth device it might be. And the desired behavior is obvious: I want it to find the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector` function to help to [enumerated paired device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm).

So, first, you need to pair the device in Windows 10 bluetooth manager or you can add code lines to pair it. And then using FindAllAsync() to get it.

About how to pair device in code, you can reference [Device enumeration and pairing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing).

Comment: You are right I need to be paired first however the problem was that it isn't listed as HC-05 as shown in the bluetooth manager, but as a "Dev B" for some odd reason. However it doesn't return any service so.. yeah. Whenever I try something out it is never as easy as it might seem to be.